# Base64 coreutils encoding padding (trailing "=" characters)

Tags: bash, base64

If I base64 encode a string which consists of seven characters e.g. `abcdefg` with the website https://www.base64encode.org/ the result is `YWJjZGVmZw==`. The trailing "==" characters are padding because the number of input characters cannot be divided by 7.

I've to reproduce this result in bash. So I've tried the following command:

```
echo "abcdefg" | base64
```

However, the result is different now:

```
YWJjZGVmZwo=
```

I'm using Ubuntu where base64 (GNU coreutils) 8.25 is installed.

I would be glad if someone could give me a hint.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've just noticed that the reason for the described behaviour is the newline which `echo` writes at the end. So the correct command is the following which suppress the newline

```
echo -n "abcdefg" | base64
```

Then the output is like I expect it:

```
YWJjZGVmZw==
```

Comment: Better use `printf`

Answer (score 0):

It is also tricky how a here-string will produce unexpected output. It is probably missing the null character \0.

```
$ base64 <<<"abcdefg"
YWJjZGVmZwo=
$ printf 'abcdefg' | base64
YWJjZGVmZw==
```